# Fastest way to tell if two files have the same contents in Unix/Linux?

Tags: linux, file, unix, diff

I have a shell script in which I need to check whether two files contain the same data or not. I do this a for a lot of files, and in my script the `diff` command seems to be the performance bottleneck.

Here's the line:

```bash
diff -q $dst $new > /dev/null

if ($status) then ...
```

Could there be a faster way to compare the files, maybe a custom algorithm instead of the default `diff`?

Comment: This is really nitpicking, but you're not asking to see if two files are the same, you're asking if two files have identical content. Same files have identical inodes (and same device).

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer, the measurement in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153612/87704) does not recognize any notable difference between `diff` and `cmp`.

Answer (score 573, accepted):

I believe `cmp` will stop at the first byte difference:

```bash
cmp --silent $old $new || echo "files are different"
```

Comment: How can I add more commands than only one? I want to copy a file and roboot.

Comment: @DanielBrunner: You can copy from the standard input to both a file and standard output by using the `tee` command.

Comment: Note that on my `cmp` I didn't have to shortcut it to echo, it will print a message if they differ or stay silent if they don't.

Comment: @eresonance Right, the example is simply meant to show how you'd capture the return status in order to script a conditional.

Comment: `cmp -s $old $new` also works. `-s` is short for `--silent`

Comment: As a speed boost, you should check the file sizes are equal before comparing the content. Does anyone know if cmp does this?

Comment: To run multiple commands, you can use brackets:

 cmp -s old new || { echo not; echo the; echo same; }

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 yes, any decent implementation of `cmp` will check file size first. Here's the GNU version, if you want to see the additional optimizations it includes: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/cmp.c

Comment: @RyanGraham thanks for the link. I see that if the -s or --silent switch is used then it will use the size check to immediately exit if the files are different sizes. I see it also has a few other optimisations like 0 sized files, or files with the same inode (ie both files are links to the same file).

Comment: I think the fastest (to type) is `cmp -l $old $new`, and you get no output for same and a lot for different files, lol

Comment: What @Rohmer mentioned (the `-s` option) is also portable, `--silent` is not defined in POSIX standard.

Answer (score 82):

I like @Alex Howansky have used 'cmp --silent' for this.  But I need both positive and negative response so I use:

```bash
cmp --silent file1 file2 && echo '### SUCCESS: Files Are Identical! ###' || echo '### WARNING: Files Are Different! ###'
```

I can then run this in the terminal or with a ssh to check files against a constant file.

Comment: If your `echo success` command (or whatever other command you put in its place) fails, your "negative response" command will be run.  You should use an "if-then-else-fi" construct.  For example, like [this simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16034851/5419599).

Answer (score 49):

To quickly **and safely** compare any two files:

```sh
if cmp --silent -- "$FILE1" "$FILE2"; then
  echo "files contents are identical"
else
  echo "files differ"
fi
```

It's readable, efficient, and works for any file names including `` "` $() ``

Answer (score 22):

Because I suck and don't have enough reputation points I can't add this tidbit in as a comment.

But, if you are going to use the `cmp` command (and don't need/want to be verbose) you can just grab the exit status. Per the `cmp` man page:

> If  a FILE is '-' or missing, read standard input.  Exit status is 0
> if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.

So, you could do something like:

```bash
STATUS="$(cmp --silent $FILE1 $FILE2; echo $?)"  # "$?" gives exit status for each comparison

if [[ $STATUS -ne 0 ]]; then  # if status isn't equal to 0, then execute code
    DO A COMMAND ON $FILE1
else
    DO SOMETHING ELSE
fi
```

EDIT: Thanks for the comments everyone! I updated the test syntax here. However, I would suggest you use Vasili's answer if you are looking for something similar to this answer in readability, style, and syntax.

Comment: yes, but this is actually more complicated way of doing `cmp --silent $FILE1 $FILE2 ; if [ "$?" == "1" ]; then echo "files differ"; fi` which in turn is a more complicated way of doing `cmp --silent $FILE1 $FILE2 || echo "files differ"` because you can use command in expression directly. It substitutes for `$?`. As a result command's exist status will be compared. And that's what the other answer does. btw. If someone is struggling with `--silent`, it's not supported everywhere (busybox). use `-s`

Comment: This can be simplified to just `if cmp --silent -- "$FILE1" "$FILE2"; then ... else ... fi`

Comment: as @VasiliNovikov pointed out, you can just do `if command; then ... else ... fi`

also, @Gregory your code has a common bash pitfall. `[[` is in fact a bash syntax and it should go as follows: `if [[ ... ]]` (notice the spaces)

A very good URL to read up on common bash pitfalls: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: @Chevraut after re-reading this QA and noticing that all current suggestions are not fully safe, I've created my own answer (basically same as I wrote here in comment)

Answer (score 8):

You can compare by checksum algorithm like sha256

```bash
sha256sum oldFile > oldFile.sha256

echo "$(cat oldFile.sha256) newFile" | sha256sum --check

newFile: OK
```

if the files are distinct the result will be

```
newFile: FAILED
sha256sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

Comment: No need to save the hash in a separate file, just compute them both and check: `echo "$(sha256sum "$1" | sed 's/ .*//') $2" | sha256sum --check 1>/dev/null`

Answer (score 3):

For files that are not different, any method will require having read both files entirely, even if the read was in the past.

There is no alternative.  So creating hashes or checksums at some point in time requires reading the whole file. Big files take time.

File metadata retrieval is much faster than reading a large file.

So, is there any file metadata you can use to establish that the files are different?
File size ?  or even results of the file command which does just read a small portion of the file?

File size example code fragment:

```bash
  ls -l $1 $2 | 
  awk 'NR==1{a=$5} NR==2{b=$5} 
       END{val=(a==b)?0 :1; exit( val) }'
       
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo 'same' || echo 'different'
```

If the files are the same size then you are stuck with full file reads.

Comment: Use `ls -n` to avoid issues if user or group names have whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Try also to use the cksum command:

```bash
chk1=`cksum <file1> | awk -F" " '{print $1}'`
chk2=`cksum <file2> | awk -F" " '{print $1}'`

if [ $chk1 -eq $chk2 ]
then
  echo "File is identical"
else
  echo "File is not identical"
fi
```

The cksum command will output the byte count of a file. See 'man cksum'.

Comment: That was my first thought too. However, hashes make sense if you have to compare the same file many times, as the hash is computed only once. If you're comparing it only once, then `md5` reads the whole file anyway, so `cmp`, stopping at the first difference, will be way faster.

Comment: Stopping at the first difference is only faster when you are expecting differences to be common.  If, for example, you are wanting to validate that files have replicated correctly then the expected outcome is all files should be the same, so you don't get any benefit except when something is "wrong" and a file doesn't match.
I'm interested in seeing if cksum has a speed benefit for some other reason and I'm going to do some real world testing on identical files to see which is faster.

Comment: Result: in my testing cmp is much faster than cksum even in worst case (when entire file is identical).  It looks like cksum is doing something quite inefficient with how it requests reads from the file because I can't imagine calculating the hash would be the bottleneck, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some testing with a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (I'm using an overlay file system, and need to sync periodically), I ran a comparison of my own for diff -q and cmp -s; note that this is a log from inside /dev/shm, so disk access speeds are a non-issue:

```
[root@mypi shm]# dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.file bs=1M count=100 ; time diff -q test.file test.copy && echo diff true || echo diff false ; time cmp -s test.file test.copy && echo cmp true || echo cmp false ; cp -a test.file test.copy ; time diff -q test.file test.copy && echo diff true || echo diff false; time cmp -s test.file test.copy && echo cmp true || echo cmp false
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 6.2564 s, 16.8 MB/s
Files test.file and test.copy differ

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s
diff false

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.001s
cmp false
cp: overwrite âtest.copyâ? y

real    0m0.966s
user    0m0.447s
sys     0m0.518s
diff true

real    0m0.785s
user    0m0.211s
sys     0m0.573s
cmp true
[root@mypi shm]# pico /root/rwbscripts/utils/squish.sh
```

I ran it a couple of times.  cmp -s consistently had slightly shorter times on the test box I was using.  So if you want to use cmp -s to do things between two files....

```
identical (){
  echo "$1" and "$2" are the same.
  echo This is a function, you can put whatever you want in here.
}
different () {
  echo "$1" and "$2" are different.
  echo This is a function, you can put whatever you want in here, too.
}
cmp -s "$FILEA" "$FILEB" && identical "$FILEA" "$FILEB" || different "$FILEA" "$FILEB"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could compare hashes, e.g. SHA-256 or MD5.

```bash
same-contents() {
    echo "$(sha256sum "$1" | sed 's/ .*//') $2" | sha256sum --check 1>/dev/null 2>&1
}
alias same-file="same-contents" # Technically the same "file" has the same inode
```

```bash
if same-contents file1.txt file2.txt; then 
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

That is essentially what was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63646240) answer, but they overcomplicate things by storing the hash in a file first. The `sed` call trims off the filename to leave only the hash.

You should likely still prefer `cmp` because it is purpose-built for this and can compare byte-by-byte, whereas hashing necessitates reading the entire files, but I thought this was an interesting script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for more customizable diff for this, then `git diff` can be used.

```bash
if (git diff --no-index --quiet old.txt new.txt) then
  echo "files contents are identical"
else
  echo "files differ"
fi
```

> **--quiet**
>
> Disable all output of the program. Implies --exit-code.

> **--exit-code**
>
> Make the program exit with codes similar to diff(1). That is, it exits with 1 if there were differences and 0 means no differences.

---

Also, there are various algorithms and settings to choose from: [[ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)]

> --diff-algorithm={patience|minimal|histogram|myers}
>
> Choose a diff algorithm. The variants are as follows:
>
> **default, myers** The basic greedy diff algorithm. Currently, this is the
> default.
>
> **minimal** Spend extra time to make sure the smallest possible diff is
> produced.
>
> **patience** Use "patience diff" algorithm when generating patches.
>
> **histogram** This algorithm extends the patience algorithm to "support
> low-occurrence common elements".