# if, elif, else statement issues in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I can't seem to work out what the issue with the following `if` statement is in regards to the `elif` and `then`. Keep in mind the `printf` is still under development I just haven't been able to test it yet in the statement so is more than likely wrong.

The error I'm getting is:

```
./timezone_string.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./timezone_string.sh: line 14: `then'
```

And the statement is like so.

```
if [ "$seconds" -eq 0 ];then
   $timezone_string="Z"
elif[ "$seconds" -gt 0 ]
then
   $timezone_string=`printf "%02d:%02d" $seconds/3600 ($seconds/60)%60`
else
   echo "Unknown parameter"
fi
```

Comment: I wonder why we **need** the `then` statement in `if` and `elif` but not in `else`, and also in general.

Comment: @w17t, because we need to separate condition from sequence.

Comment: @codeforester I don't see much logic on marking a 500K views question as a duplicate to one that has only 5K

Comment: Using some code auto-formatting tools might help you by automatically adding/removing spaces around the brackets. You can search for plugins for your editor.

Comment: for me , i never expected a semicolon at the end of 'if' statement followed by 'then'.Your question itself was the solution for me. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 549, accepted):

There is a space missing between `elif` and `[`:

```
elif[ "$seconds" -gt 0 ]
```

should be

```
elif [ "$seconds" -gt 0 ]
```

All together, the syntax to follow is:

```
if [ conditions ]; then
   # Things
elif [ other_conditions ]; then
   # Other things
else
   # In case none of the above occurs
fi
```

---

As I see this question is getting a lot of views, it is important to indicate that the syntax to follow is:

```bash
if [ conditions ]
# ^ ^          ^
```

meaning that **spaces are needed around the brackets**. Otherwise, it won't work. This is because `[` itself *is* a command.

The reason why you are not seeing something like `elif[: command not found` (or similar) is that after seeing `if` and `then`, the shell is looking for either `elif`, `else`, or `fi`.  However it finds another `then` (after the mis-formatted `elif[`).  Only *after* having parsed the statement it would be executed (and an error message like `elif[: command not found` would be output).

Comment: The reason the brackets need spaces is because they are just shortcuts for actual programs (at least the first bracket, the second one is just syntactic sugar as I understand it). To make sense of it, see the actual manpage for left bracket: `$ man [`

Comment: Is this post not supposed to be closed as typo?

Comment: @zx8754 could have been, but not it became a canonical way to fix this error, which looks quite useful (360K views and counting).

Comment: Still, closing the post doesn't make it any less valid. But of course it is up to you, I am not frequent in "bash/linux" tags.

Comment: Some of my colleagues don't understand the concept of a "space" or "coding style" so this might not be a typo.

Comment: @MichaelJohansen in my centos7 the input `$ man [` got output `bash: $: command not found...`, what is wrong?

Comment: [ is a kind of alias for the test command. This is why the blank character is required. `if test "$seconds" -eq 0; then ... fi` is equivalent to `if [ "$seconds" -eq 0 ];then ... fi ]`. @LeiYang `man test`is what you actually looking for

Answer (score 346):

You have some syntax issues with your script. Here is a fixed version:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$seconds" -eq 0 ]; then
   timezone_string="Z"
elif [ "$seconds" -gt 0 ]; then
   timezone_string=$(printf "%02d:%02d" $((seconds/3600)) $(((seconds / 60) % 60)))
else
   echo "Unknown parameter"
fi
```

Comment: Oddly enough, this was the only complete and *simple* `bash` "if-then-else" construct I easily found on stackexchange...thanks.

Comment: indentation is optional. the interpreter can (and should) be `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: @Chinggis6 Total nonsense, the interpreter **could** be `#!/bin/sh` but doesn't have to.

Comment: @Camusensei it's not a total nonsense as `sh` can be used instead for higher compatibility (not all *nix distros has [tag:bash] as the default shell (some have ksh or ash but most of them do depend on the standard `sh` to function). Moreover if bash's specific or advanced features is not being used in the script then 'sh' should be used as the interpreter (one more reason for it) as it can handle the script by itself.

Comment: @Chinggis6 True, bad choice of words on my side.

Answer (score 29):

`[` is a command (or a builtin in some shells). It must be separated by whitespace from the preceding statement:

```
elif [
```

Comment: It is superseeded by a builtin in bash, but your message is still correct. use `type -a [` to see that.

Comment: It's also a binary which always seemed odd to me.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend you having a look at the basics of conditioning in bash.

The symbol **"["** is a command and must have a whitespace prior to it. If you don't give whitespace after your elif, the system interprets **elif[** as a a particular command which is definitely not what you'd want at this time.

**Usage:**

```
elif(A COMPULSORY WHITESPACE WITHOUT PARENTHESIS)[(A WHITE SPACE WITHOUT PARENTHESIS)conditions(A WHITESPACE WITHOUT PARENTHESIS)]
```

In short, edit your code segment to:

```
elif [ "$seconds" -gt 0 ]
```

**You'd be fine with no compilation errors. Your final code segment should look like this:**

```
#!/bin/sh    
if [ "$seconds" -eq 0 ];then
       $timezone_string="Z"
    elif [ "$seconds" -gt 0 ]
    then
       $timezone_string=`printf "%02d:%02d" $seconds/3600 ($seconds/60)%60`
    else
       echo "Unknown parameter"
    fi
```

Answer (score 6):

Missing space between `elif` and `[` rest your program is correct. you need to correct it an check it out. here is fixed program:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$seconds" -eq 0 ]; then
   timezone_string="Z"
elif [ "$seconds" -gt 0 ]; then
   timezone_string=$(printf "%02d:%02d" $((seconds/3600)) $(((seconds / 60) % 60)))
else
   echo "Unknown parameter"
fi
```

useful link related to this [bash if else statement](https://speedysense.com/bash-if-else-statement/)