# Sub Function in Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, unix

I just wanna to implement simple `if & then`statement in my Script, but in two part. If the first one (**primary**) became successful then only the ***second one*** will be get execute, else it will be get Exit.

Like -

```
# script_1.sh 
function() 
{ 
    sub_function() 
    {
        #cmd
    }
 }
```

`#script_2.sh source script_1.sh function sub_function`

How it could be possible ?

Comment: From the description, it's very difficult to understand what you're trying to do and where you're having trouble. Can you please add some code to your question? Best would be if you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: #script_1.sh function() { sub_function() { #cmd } } #script_2.sh source script_1.sh function sub_function

Comment: Heh, if it's relevant to your question, please put it [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54682768/edit).

Comment: If my answer doesn't solve the problem that you're looking to fix, then you'll probably need to provide a better example in your question as it's still hard to understand. Give us an example of the commands you'd type into the terminal and the results you would like to get out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I might not have understood your question correctly but you might be able to use `&&`

Putting `&&` between two commands means that the second command will only be executed if the first command succeeds.

e.g.

```
[root@box ~]# echo 'first command' && echo "I am printed because the first command succeeded"
first command
I am printed because the first command succeeded
[root@box ~]# veafdasvea && echo "This string is not printed because the first command failed"
bash: veafdasvea: command not found
```

Comment: Thanks, but how could I use the `&&` Operator, while executing a two part Script ?

Comment: `./script1.sh && ./script2.sh` might do what you want. script2.sh will only run if script1.sh completes successfully. Does that make sense?

Comment: You're a simply Genius.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've also added some info about if/else statements in case you're interested. Feel free to upvote my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Lot of Thanks for the update, actually I was planning to execute more than two or three sub-script in same manner, but while using `else` you can go up to just one Level only.

Comment: So .. your `if [[ $(...) ]]` example is a problem. The stuff inside `[[ ... ]]` needs to follow what's documented in the **CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS** section of the bash man page. It's based on `/bin/test`, and one should NOT rely on the output of `command_that_could_whatever` to produce appropriate expressions.  If you want to test the result of a command, simply use: `if command; then`.

Comment: Thanks @ghoti , I've removed the offending example as the user wasn't after if statements anyway. But I see what I did wrong (using the output of the command rather than `if command; then` which uses the return code instead of the output).

Comment: Is it possible to adding a new statement of `if & then` into the `then` of Previous one ? I mean in that way also we can achieve the same objective as well.

Comment: Kind of. You can do `if, elif, elif, elif, then` with as many or as few `elif`s as you like. If the first condition is false, the second one is checked, if that one is false, the third is checked. If any condition is passed, then the code block below it is executed. If no code blocks pass, then the code under the `else` block is applied.

Comment: For an example of an if, elif, else format, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16034851/3465014