# Deducing the version of publicly-available Java code from compiled classes

Tags: java, dependencies, shared-libraries, versioning, software-distribution

I'm currently working with an old Java SE project which has got some version of [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) as a dependency (e.g. referring to [org.slf4j.Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html)), but the relevant classes are packaged in a very strange JAR simply called `commons.jar`, and I couldn't find any matching libraries on the Internet which have contents matching this file; **Is there any "intelligent" way of finding code which matches the compiled Java class files found inside this JAR file?** The file itself has no [metadata](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#The_META-INF_directory) of any kind — only compiled `*.class` files:

```
commons.jar
├── apache
│   ├── commons 
│   ├── http
│   ├── log4j
├── slf4j
```

As shown in the structure above, the JAR doesn't seem to "belong" to any commonly-available distributor; Even though it contains the terms *apache*, *commons*, *log**, and *slf4j*, it doesn't seem to be from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) or from SLF4J.

### Current approach

At the moment, the best I can think of is to download a bunch of versions of SLF4J, extract them, and then run e.g. [`cmp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900693/1391325) on the `org/slf4j/Logger.class` file from the mystery JAR and the analogous `Logger.class` file from each version, e.g.

```
cmp commons/org/slf4j/Logger.class slf4j-1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22/org/slf4j/Logger.class
```

However, not only does that involve a lot of work, but I believe that equivalent source might be compiled slightly differently depending on the exact compiler used by the distributors of the JARs in question... meaning that they wouldn't be comparable on a byte-per-byte basis. How might I do this kind of search in a more intelligent way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about reflecting across all public and private classes and their members, put them in strings, sort the strings and generate a text file for each version.

You will either find exactly one version of the library that matches the mystery version of the library or a smallish range.

Comment: Nice idea, and can probably automated nicely!

Comment: This is a very cool idea and I will indeed try it out. Unfortunately, it may take a bit of time before I can get this solution going...

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the following:

- bytecode Java version, gives you a clue about the time that library was built
- decompile everything... Maybe you are lucky and find some comments / version constants that give you further clues