# How to check if a diff command is successful in Unix shell script

Tags: shell, if-statement, unix, diff, checksum

In a Unix shell script, I want to check if the output of a diff command is equal to 0 through an if statement. So that I can accordingly give the if case statements.

For example:
Abc.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd users
diff s1 d1 > a.txt
wc -l a.txt | awk '{print f1}' > a
echo "value of a is"
cat a
if [ $a == 0 ]
  then
echo "checksums match"
  else
echo "checksums do not match"
fi
```

Output:

```
value of a is
0
[: ==: unary operator expected
checksums do not match
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to tell if two files have the same contents in Unix/Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900538/fastest-way-to-tell-if-two-files-have-the-same-contents-in-unix-linux)

Comment: `diff -q s1 d1 &>/dev/null && echo "checksums match" || echo "checksums do not match"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to fix your script, but this is probably the most minimal:

```
a=$(cat a)
if [ "$a" = "" ]; then
```

1. Variables are different from files, so you have to read the output of the file you created.
2. Variables that potentially contain spaces must be quoted when used as arguments, and strings must be compared against empty rather than 0.

(As suggested in the comment, if you don't need the `diff` output, you could just use the exit code.)

Comment: Thank you. This partly worked. if [ "$a" == 0 ] then echo "checksums match" else echo "checksums don't match".. this has worked

Answer (score 1):

Just check diff.

```
if diff s1 d1 ; then
   echo "checksums match"
else
   echo "checksums do not match"
fi
```

If you don't want to have output on terminal, you would use `cmp`.

```
if cmp -s s1 d2 ; then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1** : quick note on short-circuiting

before u even start to consider which of the comparison tools, check their file sizes via `stat` command.

if even those don't match, then it's close to statistically impossible for any hashing algorithm to report a matching hash.

One method I use myself is

1. check file sizes
2. for matching ones, do a high speed batch run of them over `xxhash`.
3. then finally, ***only*** for the suggested duplicates from step 2, run them once more via a cryptographically acceptable hash, like `Keccak` or `Shake` from `SHA3` family, to confirm they're truly duplicates beyond all reasonable doubt

==============================

`awk` has a useful feature of having `NR = 0` if you only have an `END` block, but nothing got read in, either from files or from pipe.

One can also re-use the same string for both scenarios w/o using a ternary operator `… ? … : …` by leveraging the `0th-power of any base`.

if u don't have too many files, here's a pretty brute force but high speed way to do it all at once.

```
--just remove the bckgrnd placing bit "... & )"  if u wanna do it sequentially
```

|

```
for f1 in "${m2p}" "${m3l}" "${m3m}";              do 
for f2 in "${m3m}" "${m2a}" "${m2p}" "${m3supp}" ; do 

    ( diff "${f1}" "${f2}" |  

      {m,g}awk -F'^$' -v __="${f1}" -v ___="${f2}" '
      END {
              ____=ENVIRON["HOME"] 
          sub(____,"~",__)
          sub(____,"~",___)
      
          print "checksums for \n\t\42"(__)"\42\n\t\b\b\b\band \42"\
                                       (___)"\42 ===> "   \
          substr(" DO NOT match", ((_+= ++_)^++_+!!_)^!NR)"\n" }' &)
      
done ; done | gcat -b


 1  checksums for 
 2      "~/m2map_main.txt"
 3      and "~/m2map_main.txt" ===> match

 4  checksums for 
 5      "~/m3vid_genie26.txt"
 6      and "~/m3vid_genie26.txt" ===> match

 7  checksums for 
 8      "~/m3vid_genie26.txt"
 9      and "~/m2art_main_03.txt" ===>  DO NOT match

10  checksums for 
11      "~/m3vid_genie26.txt"
12      and "~/m3vid_genie25_supp.txt" ===>  DO NOT match

13  checksums for 
14      "~/m23lyricsFLT_05.txt"
15      and "~/m3vid_genie26.txt" ===>  DO NOT match

16  checksums for 
17      "~/m23lyricsFLT_05.txt"
18      and "~/m2art_main_03.txt" ===>  DO NOT match

19  checksums for 
20      "~/m23lyricsFLT_05.txt"
21      and "~/m3vid_genie25_supp.txt" ===>  DO NOT match

22  checksums for 
23      "~/m3vid_genie26.txt"
24      and "~/m2map_main.txt" ===>  DO NOT match

25  checksums for 
26      "~/m2map_main.txt"
27      and "~/m3vid_genie26.txt" ===>  DO NOT match

28  checksums for 
29      "~/m2map_main.txt"
30      and "~/m2art_main_03.txt" ===>  DO NOT match

31  checksums for 
32      "~/m2map_main.txt"
33      and "~/m3vid_genie25_supp.txt" ===>  DO NOT match

34  checksums for 
35      "~/m23lyricsFLT_05.txt"
36      and "~/m2map_main.txt" ===>  DO NOT match
```